# MS Teams app localization using manifest not working

Tags: localization, manifest, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to localize my app by following instructions as outlined in the [Teams docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/publishing/apps-localization). Despite making the changes nearly identically to what's provided on the site, the text does not localize in my app.

I'm using version 1.5 of the manifest so localization should be supported.

manifest.json:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.5",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "packageName": "com.foobar.myapp",
    "localizationInfo": {
        "defaultLanguageTag": "en-us",
        "additionalLanguages": [
            {
                "languageTag": "fr-ca",
                "file": "fr-ca.json"
            }
        ]
     },
    "developer": {
        "name": "FooBar",
        "websiteUrl": "https://www.foobar.com/",
        "privacyUrl": "https://www.foobar.com/privacy-policy",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.foobar.com/collaborative-canvas"
     },
    "icons": {
        "color": "color.png",
        "outline": "outline.png"
    },
    "name": {
        "short": "Foo Bar",
        "full": "FooFoo BarBar"
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "Content",
        "full": "Some more content"
     },
    "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "staticTabs": [
        {
            "entityId": "TestId",
            "name": "Test",
            "contentUrl": "https://foobar.net/Test",
            "scopes": [
                "personal"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
         "identity"
    ],
    "validDomains": [
        "foobar.net"
    ],
    "devicePermissions": [
        "openExternal"
    ]
}
```

fr-ca.json:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.Localization.schema.json",
    "name.short": "FooBar translated",
    "name.full": "FooFoo BarBar translated",
    "description.short": "test short",
    "description.full": "test full translation",
    "staticTabs[0].name": "test translated"
}
```

When I zip the package app manifest package, I ensure that the fr-ca.json file is included.

I've also changed my Teams language settings to French (Canada) so I'm not sure why the localization is not being picked up.

I'm aware that localization is not yet available for apps published to the Teams app store but from my understanding it should work fine for self-uploaded personal apps. I've tried uploading it both via the Applications menu as well as the App Studio.

Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RizJa Your manifest file works as expected for me:
[image]

Here is the language setting that I made to get this working:
[image]

Could you please share a screenshot of what is the language setting you have used?

Comment: I'm at a loss for words. I tried this with my app the day I posted this question and it didn't work. Seeing your response, I tried the same thing today (with a new app exact same as in this question) and it worked. Thinking I may have missed something in my app (the only thing different being the text content and app id), I tested my app again (with no changes whatsoever) and in the exact same way and it worked! Perhaps it was a caching issue of some sort or something else but there was definitely something different between then and now. My language settings resembled yours exactly as well.

Comment: I'll still mark this as the answer as the language settings in conjunction with the manifest and localization file provided in the question do yield the expected localized result. Thanks.